# Lots of tables, no go

Tags: tables, floats

I have a file with +30 tables that I would really like LaTex to parse but of course it gets all floaty and can't decide where to place them and so goes belly up. Any suggestions on on how to get this done?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you have so many tables without surrounding text, then don't use floats. There are ways to define captions without float environments.

Comment: Minimal example with 30 tables? Tricky. What I can say is that the tables are standard just lots of them.

Comment: @knut Such as? ldhalsfhkjdfhsakljdfhaslkjdf

Comment: There isn't an "of course" if the floats are not being positioned, either the markup isn't ideal, or they shouldn't be floats at all, but no one can can say what's wrong of you give no hints what you did. Do you use `\begin{table}[h]` for example? That's a common cause of the effect you describe.

Comment: Each table looks something like this:   \begin{table}
   \caption{Ordinary Kriging assesment, ablation 2004. Graded: Fail, Pass or Good}
   \label{tab:OKbs04_ass}
   \begin{tabular}{@{}lccl} \hline

Comment: I have now split the tables into individual tex files, each of which parses on its own but now, ah now, \include fails instead. Forgive my terseness but I really, really don't have time to be dealing with this and am frankly more than a little miffed at having to battle Python, Latex, ArcGIS, QGIS and bash every damned step of the way. Most of my PhD isn't about science it's about getting programmes to do what they are allegedly supposed to be able to do. Rant, puff, rant.

Comment: Lots of people here could help but really you don't seem to be wanting help, just wanting to let off steam, which is Ok if that's what you need to do. \include won't fail unless you misuse it but we can't guess how that is, but actually you don't want \include unless you want each table on a separate page, you want \input (bt that's same as putting all the tables in one file.

Comment: Well, the tables parse in their individual tex files, I use e.g. \include{./AppTab1.tex} to call each one and they are stubbornly not found. Right now I don't care if they are on the same page or not, I would just like to know why this latest problem has occurred  (already given up on the original "get everything to work from one file" thing). If you want more code then I can cp the entire article but I suspect you don't want that. They are tables, bog standard tables, by the book tables.

Comment: @mercergeoinfo If you get the syntax wrong, most programs don't work. You shouldn't use the `.tex` extension in `\include` just as you don't use the .sty extension in \usepackage

Comment: Ah! But that's not what http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents claims. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: And it didn't work either. Nice try though

Comment: "didn't work" is not a useful description if you want help, but anyway if you have a long series of tables with no intervening text you should do as in my answer.

Comment: The wikibook you link to does say exactly what I said: `\include{Chapter_1}                % omit the '.tex' extension`

Comment: If `\include` is failing, you can make an MWE with just *one* table, can't you? That should be straightforward. Also omit the `./` at the beginning. They're in the same directory anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This document has 144 tables without problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}

\centering
\section{foo}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\section{foo}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\section{foo}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\section{foo}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\section{foo}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\section{foo}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\section{foo}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\section{foo}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{hmmm}\begin{tabular}{ll}a\\b\\c\\d\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It's safer to use `\captionof` inside some containing environment (`center` or `minipage`, for example); otherwise (if real contents is in between), strange things can happen :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina well a minipage would prevent a page break between the caption and the table which is probably a good idea, I can't see how `center` would make any difference other than adding vertical space?